# Swaping the negative values into zeroes in a numpy array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, format

How can I write a code that swaps all the negative values of `a` into zeroes.

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([12,12,123,4,-4,0.15,-100])
```

Expected Output:

```
[12,12,123,4,0,0.15,0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the clip function from numpy

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html

```
a.clip(min = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
format_number = lambda n: n if n % 1 else int(n)
a = list(map(lambda n: 0 if n < 0 else format_number(n), a))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[12, 12, 123, 4, 0, 0.15, 0]
```